# Cross compiling on mac for windows

Tags: macos, cross-compiling

Can I compile on mac so it will produce a windows binary? bind with windows dlls? (I have a windows machine to copy them from) How can I do so? clang and gcc are the compilers I can use.

Answer (score 5):

These instructions will work on both MacOS and Linux, but I will provide them from a Mac perspective.

1. [Download Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)
2. Add a Windows [dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross)

If you don't know how to use docker then just download [Kitematic](https://kitematic.com/) (Links to an external site.).

From Kitematic you can simply click the "+New" button and get the dockcross image from the docker hub.

After the image downloads in Kitematic, click the "Docker CLI" button in the bottom left. This will open a new terminal window setup for the docker environment.

From that terminal window:

cd to the directory with the project you want to build then save a shellscript that will run the docker container and build the project:

1. `docker run --rm dockcross/windows-x86 > ./dockcross`
2. `chmod +x ./dockcross`
3. `./dockcross make` (assuming your project uses a makefile)

See the dockcross documentation for more examples and further guidance.

dockcross uses MXE, so you can pretty easily build most projects, but you may need to install additional [MXE packages](http://mxe.cc/#packages)

Answer (score 3):

The MinGW's toolchain can be built on OSX or most other unix/unix-like operating systems.

Here's a link to the precompiled binaries: http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=mingw-older-releases

It works fine on my PowerMac G5 and as keith.layne says there is also a solution for Intel Macs.