# Can you install winegcc/wineg++ on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, mingw, wine

I am writing a c++ program specifically for Windows operating system. However, I am writing it on a Mac OS. I know it seems counter productive, but I have my reasons that would take the next paragraph to explain. What I want is to be able to compile it on my Mac, and turn it into a .exe file, but I won't be running it on a Mac. I'll be running it on a Windows machine. The header that I want to use, but I obviously have problems with is `windows.h`. Using the standard g++ on a Mac I am unable to do this.

However, winegcc using wineg++ is able to do this. I have seen that you are able to install these on a Linux machine. I want to know if it is possible to do on a Mac as well.

Comment: I'd rather recommend to install MinGW for cross compiling. I never tried that, but I believe it's the better choice over wine. Here are some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708156/cross-compiling-on-mac-for-windows

Comment: Thank you Worked Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to import `windows.h` on a Mac OS, you just won't be able to run it on a Mac OS

The comment that said to install MinGW worked great. I just ran `brew install mingw-w64` in terminal, then this example command worked on a mac and compiled a windows executable file:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ shell.cpp -o shellv1.exe -lws2_32 -s -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-write-strings -fno-exceptions -fmerge-all-constants -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`